# Deploying k3os through a single image across all nodes with a shared token

Tags: k3s

I'm trying to get a k3os cluster running on a set of Raspberry Pi nodes using https://github.com/sgielen/picl-k3os-image-generator.  I'm successfully generating images and I am able to boot from them.  However, even though I have a token entry in each of my config files (token and secret replaced):

```
k3os:
  token: K10e8c37ea0000000000000000000000000000002cbdaef2f8d7bd2f5b6931b4f52b::server:secret
```

when the first node boots, it seems to generate a new secret for the cluster anyway, which means the other nodes can't join.  I know I can pull out the new token from the cluster and rebuild the images, but I'd rather figure out how to have one image that I create once and use.  I'm sure I'm missing something silly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that k3os is dead

https://github.com/rancher/k3os/issues/846

and its replacement is basically dead

https://github.com/rancher/k3os/issues/846#issuecomment-1040252582

so I have decided just to give up and use a normal OS and normal management, because I don't have time to fight this any longer.